NetworkManager keeps creating new ethernet interfaces
I'm trying to setup a Raspberry Pi 4 to a static IP address using this guide:
https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2024/set-static-ip-address-nmtui-on-raspberry-pi-os-12-bookworm
I setup static IP address, Gateway, DNS servers and it works fine until I reboot.
Then the NetworkManager creates a new interface with the same name but without Gateway and DNS info. Only with IP address.

nmcli device status gives:

The issue is that I cannot access internet if I don't have Gateway and DNS setup properly.
It only works until I reboot, then it creates another interface with empty fields of DNS and Gateway.
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
          Kernel: Linux 6.6.20+rpt-rpi-v8
    Architecture: arm64


please do not post a picture of text ... post thevtext instead ... format as code for readability

how do you know that the interface is created by the NetworkManager and not some other program

@jsotola I'm not sure about that. What other program could do that? How can I find it?

add those questions to your post

Since you relied upon Jeff Geerling's tutorial, why not ask him for an answer? There is a spot to leave comments... so...???

I’m voting to close this question because: 1) This is a NetworkManager question, and is not specific to Raspberry pi (try U&L SE instead), and 2) Asking someone here to review a 3rd party blog that you have followed seems awfully convoluted! Why not go back to the source of the blog for help??

You have failed to explain HOW you setup or any diagnostics. WHY do you want to set static addresses - this is a Pi disease, rarely necessary. If you left normal settings and let the router do its job it would work

Milliways had a great post on static ip address, but I can not find it now. If you are using the GUI auto login, then the instructions below may be used.

It was like put the mouse on the top right network icon.
A popup will show network connections and current ip adresses.
Single click on the icon. A pull down menu window will show several options.
Put the mouse on Advanced Options >. Select Edit Connections....
Select either Wired connection 1 or preconfigured and then click on the black gear at the bottom.
A new window will pop up. Select IPv4 Settings.
Select the drop down on Method and then select Manual.
Key in Address Netmask Gateway (may have to select Add) and DNS Server (I put (dotted gateway),9.9.9.9,8.8.8.8) then click Save if black, else select IP address line , Add, then Save (I got confussed here).

I think that I had to power off and wait until the Time To Live on the router
timed out and now I have static IP Address on Bookworm.

It's not clear whether the OP is using a GUI.

@goldilocks Very good point.
